# REST API with dotnet core

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core

Thanks for your observations, i did applied them with the following code but after testing api returns no data. I have even used my connection string instead of dbcontext still nothing! I get this error Invalid attempt to call FieldCount when reader is closed and my reader is open. i am in this situation for a week now any help. The FromSql query just returns entities of a single table. my Store procedure takes a parameter and has joins with 4 tables. i have tried with "ExecuteSqlCommand" query as results is a -1 i get.

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using ActivaMobileAgent.Persistence;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using ActivaMobileAgent.Model;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System;
using Dapper;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Common;

 namespace ActivaMobileAgent.Controllers
{
    [Route("/api/Policy")]
    public class PolicyController : Controller
    {
    private readonly ActivaMobileAgentDbContext context;

    public PolicyController(ActivaMobileAgentDbContext context) => this.context = context;

    public readonly string connectionString = "Data Source=Localhost;Initial Catalog=HELLOxx;User=sa; Password=Helloxx";

    [HttpGet("{id}")]

    public async Task<IActionResult> GetPolicy(string id)
    {
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=Localhost;Initial Catalog=Helios;User=sa; Password=P@ssw0rd"))
        {
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
            command.Connection = connection;
            command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            command.CommandText ="dbo.sproc_Contract_Get";
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ContractNumber", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = id });
            connection.Open();
            using (var result = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync())
            {
                return Json(result);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: if you want to return some data from your action method, you need a `return` statement, just like any normal C# method. Right now you simply execute your query, but you do not even look at the results, never mind return them to the caller

Comment: Also you'll need to use ```ExecuteReaderAsync()``` instead of ```ExecuteNonQueryAsync()```, but since you already have a DbContext you could maybe use [FromSql()](https://dotnetthoughts.net/how-to-execute-storedprocedure-in-ef-core/) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your web-method doesn't return any data.

Instead of having a method that returns nothing, modify the method signature to

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GetPolicy( int id )
```

Once you've done that, the compiler will expect that this method returns some data.
I suppose that the stored proc returns some data, so you'll have to put it somewhere.  Afterwards you can return the values using

```
return Ok(thedata);
```

Check the [Ok](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.apicontroller.ok(v=vs.118).aspx) method for instance.
If something went wrong, you shouldn't return Ok offcourse, but another Http status code that indicates what went wrong.

This leads me to saying that the functions in a REST service should always return the correct HTTP status code.  Therefore, all your REST methods should return IActionResult or Task, and not only the data that is retrieved

**Edit after the Question has been edited**

The ExecuteReader() method returns a class that implements IDataReader.  It's obviously not correct to return the datareader to the consumer of your webservice.
Instead, you'll have to use the IDataReader to read the data and use that data to populate some kind of model that you can use to return to the consumer of your service.

```
List<SomeClass> result = new List<SomeClass>();

using (var reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync())
{
    while( reader.Read() )
    {
        result.Add(new SomeClass(dr.GetInt32(0), dr.GetString(1));
    }
}

return Ok(result);
```

Next to that, I advise you to not format the data yourself to json or xml or whatever.  Let ASP.NET handle that for you.  ASP.NET will serialize the results to the appropriate format based on the value accept-header of the request that it has received.

Comment: Thanks for your observations, i did applied them with the following code but after testing api returns no data.

Comment: Have you debugged and investigated what exactly happens ?  you might also update your question with updated code

Comment: No still in the same situation. i have updated the question as well

Comment: The idea behind this is that i need this api to consume it with an android app.

Answer (score 0):

`ExecuteReaderAsync` returns `Task<SqlDataReader>`. This is probably not a useful type to serialize as a JSON result. It represents a cursor over a dataset, not the data itself; the data hasn't actually been brought back from the database yet. As [this blog article](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2009/Apr/24/JSON-Serialization-of-a-DataReader) explains, there isn't a built-in way to turn a SqlDataReader into JSON. There are a couple of ways mentioned there, but the take-away is that you will have to write code that iterates the SqlDataReader and constructs results from it.

Typically to make this job easier you'd use an [Object-Relational Mapper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) to do this work for you, an example is [Dapper](https://www.davepaquette.com/archive/2018/01/28/using-stored-procedures-to-load-data-with-dapper.aspx) which has support for stored procedures (disclaimer: I#ve never used Dapper). [Entity Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/) is the usual for .net applications as it's built by Microsoft, but it's quite heavy and can be complex to use.

edit: Oh - I didn't spot that you had an Entity Framework DbContext already. That should allow you to execute the stored procedure and map it to a result natively.